# How to make repeating custom expressions in SQL queries maintainable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine the following simple query, where I get a list of all users that were created within the last 3 days, *the logic or example is not important*

```
SELECT
    ...
    , DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE())
    ...
FROM
    dbo.AspNetUsers U
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 3
```

I've repeated some code `DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 3` which, when I have much more complicated examples of the above I don't want to maintain twice or however many times I need that logic.

How should one go about dealing with this with performance in mind?

Thanks

Comment: For this specific example, creating and referencing a view and applying the `WHERE` when selecting the view would mean you only define that expression once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have performance in mind, then you'd better repeat expressions when needed.
Specifically, don't try to put them in a user-defined functions. They are known to make queries slow in SQL Server.

Having said that, there are at least two methods in SQL Server to make queries more readable without affecting the performance:

1. CTE
2. CROSS APPLY

Example for use of CTE:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(

    SELECT
        ...
        , DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE()) AS CalculatedColumn
        ...
    FROM
        dbo.AspNetUsers U

)
SELECT
    ...
    CalculatedColumn
    ...
FROM CTE
WHERE
    CalculatedColumn < 3
;
```

Example for using `CROSS APPLY`:

Instead of repeating parts of the formula in the following query:

```
SELECT
    ColA + ColB AS ColSum
    ,ColA - ColB AS ColDiff
    ,(ColA + ColB) * (ColA - ColB) AS Result
    ,(ColA + ColB) * (ColA - ColB) * 100.0 AS Percentage
FROM Table
```

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to write it like this:

```
SELECT
    ColSum
    ,ColDiff
    ,Result
    ,Result * 100.0 AS Percentage
FROM
    Table
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            ColA + ColB AS ColSum
            ,ColA - ColB AS ColDiff
    ) AS A1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT ColSum * ColDiff AS Result
    ) AS A2
```

---

By the way, speaking about performance,

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 3
```

is terrible, because it can't use index on `DateCreated` (because you wrapped the column in a function).

You'd better rewrite it as something like

```
WHERE U.DateCreated > DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETUTCDATE())
```

Comment: in CTE, you are not applying any conditions, so it will scan complete table and will apply filter in recursive. so its not feasible solution for above request.

Comment: @JERRY, most likely SQL Server optimiser would generate exactly the same execution plans for the queries with and without CTE. SQL Server doesn't materialise CTE (as opposed to Postgres, for example), so performance would be the same,

Answer (score 3):

I would use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES`:

```
SELECT . . ., v.diff
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers U CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE()))
     ) v(diff)
WHERE v.diff < 3;
```

You can add multiple expressions to the values clause:

```
SELECT . . ., v.diff
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers U CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE()),
              YEAR(U.DateCreated)
             )
     ) v(diff, yyyy)
WHERE v.diff < 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to Gordon Linoff's, but using a SELECT subquery:

```
SELECT . . ., v.diff
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers U CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE()) as diff
     ) v
WHERE v.diff < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this clause `WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, U.DateCreated, GETUTCDATE()) < 3`, Index will not get seeked. so you need to apply where clause with, 
`WHERE U.DateCreated >= DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETUTCDATE())`.

Now, Your index over **U.DateCreated** will get seek and better performs. and now you can use **DATETIFF** type of functions in SELECT Statement.