# How to re-use complicated formulas multiple times in the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query with a couple of semi-complicated formulas. I've removed a lot of extra bits and boiled it down to what is relevant to my question.

```
DECLARE @Company              AS NVARCHAR(8) = 'Acme'
                  , @Plant                AS VARCHAR(20)  = 'Albuquerque'
                  , @Warehouse            AS NVARCHAR(8) = 'TNT-WH1'
                  , @DaysAhead            AS INT         = 10
                  , @FulfillmentThreshold AS INT         = 90;

            SELECT
                @Company AS 'Company'                    
                , orel.SellingReqQty
                , orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty AS 'ShippedQty'
                , orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty) AS 'ReqQtyRemaining'
                , CASE
                    WHEN ((pw.OnHandQty - (pw.AllocatedQty + pw.ReservedQty))
                            / (orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty)) * 100)
                            >= 100 THEN '100'
                    ELSE
                        ((pw.OnHandQty - (pw.AllocatedQty + pw.ReservedQty))
                            / (orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty)) * 100)
                END
                AS 'PercentAvailToFulfill'

            FROM
                dbo.OrderRel AS orel WITH (NOLOCK)

                INNER JOIN erp.PartWhse AS pw WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON (pw.Company = orel.Company AND
                        pw.PartNum = orel.PartNum AND
                        pw.WarehouseCode = @Warehouse)

            WHERE
                orel.Company = @Company                
            AND orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty) > 0 -- ReqQtyRemaining
             AND (orel.ReqDate <= DATEADD(DAY, @DaysAhead, GETDATE())
                  OR
                  orel.RushPart_c = 1 )

            AND ((pw.OnHandQty - (pw.AllocatedQty + pw.ReservedQty))
                / (orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty)) * 100)
                > @FulfillmentThreshold

            AND (orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty)) > (pw.AllocatedQty + pw.ReservedQty)
```

As you can see this bit of code which represents a remaining qty is repeated many times but is necessary to calculate for each record returned:

```
orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty)
```

I'm looking for a way to make this more readable by changing that into a single variable. Is it possible to set that as a variable calculated for each row so I can refer to it as @ReqQtyRemaining?

Comment: You can't set a variable in a statement that returns a dataset, and setting a variable per row doesn't make sense; all your variables are scalar values so they can only hold a scalar value. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you want to calculate a running total, use a windowed aggregate function. *Also, do you "need" those `NOLOCK` hints? You are aware they can easily cause your returned data to be erroneous, correct?*

Comment: Side note,  as well, it's recommended to not use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are used for literal strings, and it can be quite confusing to read. Stick to the T-SQL delimit identifiers (brackets (`[]`)) or the ISO delimit identifiers (double quotes (`""`)) if you must delimit identify your alias; otherwise don't quote them.

Comment: It appears that you just want to avoid repeating the expression `orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty)`. Perhaps evaluating it once using `cross apply` would simplify the query to your liking. Have a look at [How to make repeating custom expressions in SQL queries maintainable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54993633/92546).

Comment: @Larnu that's interesting about the quotes, I didn't know that. We're constructing these queries strings in PHP, so we normally use the double quote for the outer string and single for the inner stuff. And we have a dev that loves spaces in their aliases... `$query = "SELECT t.column AS 'my alias' ";`

Comment: @Larnu the WITH (NOLOCK) hint is used because we are "guests" on this DB so-to-speak. And as guests, we don't want to interfere with any of the database's normal operations, even if the data we get back is slightly incorrect, it's not being used to provide life or death information. I think being a guest and not locking any tables while actual production users are doing transactions is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case if all these columns are in the same table you can use `COMPUTED` column.

So, you just need to modify your table structure to add new computed column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.OrderRel ADD ReqQtyRemaining AS (SellingReqQty - OurJobShippedQty + OurStockShippedQty)
```

Once you create a computed column this column as a name said will be always automatically updated and it can be used in the query as all other columns, you just cannot update this column manually.

Then you don't need to do the calculation in the queries and the big thing that you can put an index on this column as well.

More information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

If you are unable to change table structure you can try with `CTE (Common Table Expressions)`. However, you will not see any specific performance improvement, you will just improve readability and reusability of the same code. So, then your query should look like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Company                AS NVARCHAR(8)  = 'Acme'
        , @Plant                AS VARCHAR(20)  = 'Albuquerque'
        , @Warehouse            AS NVARCHAR(8)  = 'TNT-WH1'
        , @DaysAhead            AS INT          = 10
        , @FulfillmentThreshold AS INT          = 90;

;WITH OrderRelWithComputedCTE AS
(
    SELECT *, (SellingReqQty - OurJobShippedQty + OurStockShippedQty) ReqQtyRemaining
    FROM dbo.OrderRel WITH (NOLOCK)
)
SELECT
    @Company AS 'Company'                    
    , orel.SellingReqQty
    , orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty AS 'ShippedQty'
    , orel.ReqQtyRemaining
    , CASE
        WHEN ((pw.OnHandQty - (pw.AllocatedQty + pw.ReservedQty))
                / orel.ReqQtyRemaining * 100)
                >= 100 THEN '100'
        ELSE
            ((pw.OnHandQty - (pw.AllocatedQty + pw.ReservedQty))
                / orel.ReqQtyRemaining * 100)
    END
    AS 'PercentAvailToFulfill'

FROM
    OrderRelWithComputedCTE AS orel
    INNER JOIN erp.PartWhse AS pw WITH (NOLOCK)
               ON (pw.Company = orel.Company AND
                   pw.PartNum = orel.PartNum AND
                   pw.WarehouseCode = @Warehouse)
WHERE
    orel.Company = @Company                
AND orel.SellingReqQty - (orel.OurJobShippedQty + orel.OurStockShippedQty) > 0 -- ReqQtyRemaining
 AND (orel.ReqDate <= DATEADD(DAY, @DaysAhead, GETDATE())
      OR
      orel.RushPart_c = 1 )

AND ((pw.OnHandQty - (pw.AllocatedQty + pw.ReservedQty))
    / orel.ReqQtyRemaining * 100)
    > @FulfillmentThreshold

AND orel.ReqQtyRemaining > (pw.AllocatedQty + pw.ReservedQty)
```

Pay attention on `CTE` command at the top of the SELECT statement and on this line:

```sql
FROM OrderRelWithComputedCTE AS orel
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Unfortunately in our case we wouldn't be able to alter the database at all but that might help someone else in the future with the same use case. Nice idea!

Comment: @S.Mason I have updated my answer if you are unable to change table structure.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Really good information for both of your ideas. Thanks a lot. I hope this can help someone else simplify the reuse of ugly formulas in their SQL scripts.